# In Rails, won't url_for pick up the route from the routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

I have a situation where there are lots of models and I am using STI in rails to help minimize the creation of so many models that share similar attributes.

However, I am trying to dynamically generate routes without having to duplicate controller logic.

I am using url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :show) or whatever the url should be. However, I would simply like these routes to be listed in the routes file and not have to create controller files for each. But looks like url_for expects the actual controller file to be created. Otherwise, it would generate the wrong url (its generating some auth/failure url, which, I have no idea why it is doing). How can I make it pick up the route in the routes file and not have a separate controller file?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and become familiar with `resources`.

I believe you could use the one controller for the different models. So in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :sti_model1, :controller => 'sti_controller'
resources :sti_model2, :controller => 'sti_controller'
resources :sti_model3, :controller => 'sti_controller'
```

Comment: I need something like "resources :restaurants, controller: :businesses" - but that won't work with url_for(controller: controller_name, action : index). It is generating some garbage url as I mentioned (unless I really have a controller file called restaurants_controller)